# Why is DEM layer turning black when applying multidirectional hillshade effect

Tags: qgis, dem, hillshade

I'm quite new to QGIS, and am experimenting with the hillshade effects. I've imported a DEM layer, and am simply trying to render it as a multidirectional hillshade. Every time I click the "multidirectional" option and then apply the new settings, the hillshade layer becomes completely black. I've tried changing all of the other settings, and I am able to apply them perfectly fine on their own/until I select the multidirectional option.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?

I know there must be a simple answer to this, but I haven't been able to find anything online yet.

Comment: Please can you add a screenshot which shows all the settings you have used.